# Retaining values across POST in a VERY basic php form

Tags: php, post, get

I'm going through a very basic php tutorial and am creating a calculator so I can get the hang of $_GET, $_POST and some general syntax.

I created a very basic php function `calc();` in a php file called functionadvanced.php.  All it does is take 2 numbers, an operator, does the math and spits out the results (like I said, very basic tutorial).  The function works so I won't post the code.

I have another php file called calc.php that has my form for my calculator.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
include "functionadvanced.php";

$number1 = $_POST['num1'];
$number2 = $_POST['num2'];
$operator = $_POST['op'];

?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action='calc.php' method='POST'>

    <input type='textbox' name='num1' value="<?php echo $_GET['$number1']; ?>"/> &nbsp;
    <select name="op" selected="<?php echo $_GET['$operator']; ?>">
           <option value="+">+</option>
           <option value="-">-</option>
           <option value="*">*</option>
           <option value="/">/</option>
    </select> &nbsp;
    <input type='textbox' name='num2' value="<?php echo $_GET['$number2']; ?>"/>
    <input type='submit' value='=' /> 
    <input type='text' name='result' value="<?php echo calc($number1,$number2,$operator); ?>" />

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form actually works, and shows the correct value that the calc function spits out, but when the page posts back it doesn't keep the posted back values in the fields.  I thought I was suppose to use a $_GET to grab the values posted in the $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET` refers to information passed in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (`index.php?id=123` gives `$_GET['id'] = '123'`), while `$_POST` is for form info.  These correspond roughly (but not exactly) to the matching [http request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

So you want to use `$_POST` again, or just use the variables you've already read from `$_POST` (like `$number1`).

NOTE: I know this is just a learning process, but this naive approach is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), so read up on that before going live with anything important...

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense.  I'm coming from a .NET background :)  Thank you!  Yes this is just learning, I wouldn't use this basic functionality in a live environment.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

why use $_GET when you have grabbed the values form $_POST? you just need to use them. and should also add defaults

```
<?php
include "functionadvanced.php";

$number1 = isset($_POST['num1'])?$_POST['num1']:0;
$number2 = isset($_POST['num2'])?$_POST['num2']:0;
$operator = isset($_POST['op'])?$_POST['op']:'+';

?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action='calc.php' method='POST'>

    <input name='num1' value="<?php echo $number1; ?>"/> &nbsp;
    <select name="op" selected="<?php echo $operator; ?>">
           <option value="+">+</option>
           <option value="-">-</option>
           <option value="*">*</option>
           <option value="/">/</option>
    </select> &nbsp;
    <input name='num2' value="<?php echo $number2; ?>"/>
    <input type='submit' value='=' /> 
    <input name='result' value="<?php echo calc($number1,$number2,$operator); ?>" />

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

also, there is no type="textbox", only text which is default. if you need a text box, you should use